# How to overcome problems with foreign key constraints to optimize a MySql table

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

My application writes to a table `core`; this name is immutable.  It's gotten very large (millions of rows) and so its size make INSERTs into it slower than they need be.  My solution is to only hold one week's worth of data in `core`.  So I've constructed a table `core_archive` to put everything older than one week into at scheduled intervals.

At schedule intervals a script gets all the new values in `core`, operates on them and puts them into a third table `core_details`.  The schema is such that `core_details` has a foreign key constraint to the PK in `core`.

My problem is that because of this foreign key constraint (between `core_detail` and `core`), I *cannot* delete any rows from `core`.  So what should I do?

Options:

1. Do an ALTER TABLE to point the old foreign key constraints at `core_archive`.  This really shouldn't and maybe can't be done safely on a large production database, though.
2. ? [I have no other viable ideas...any thoughts StackO?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a `core_details_archive` table as well and archive the rows of `core_archive` that point to rows of `core` that are scheduled to be archived. Depending on your data structure, this approach may need to be extended to any number of tables.

Comment: Yeah, so far this seems like the only option.  Thanks for suggestion.